# EM Out/Headphones and amplifier recording

Tags: recording, amplifiers, homerecording

[image]

I have got this practice amplifier and as it is seen it has got an EM OUT/Phones output jack where you can directly listen to your guitar through headphones.

My question is If I would buy a male-to-male jack audio cable (like this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NO73MUQ))  and then plug it into both amplifier and to computer's microphone/headphones jack will I be able to record my guitar directly?

I asked a similar question before and the answer I got was "You need to preamplify the guitar's signal". I suppose since it is coming directly from amplifier it is already amplified so I will be able to record this audio like it is coming from a microphone. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The em. out/ phones jack will be 'preamplified', so you should be able to plug it in to your computer and get a strong enough signal to record. (I think em. Out stands for speaker **em**ulation - i.e. they try to make it still sound like it's coming through a speaker cabinet).

However, whether that will be enough to do the recording jobs you want to do depends on some other factors. If you just want to record what you're playing solo and leave it at that, then this setup might be good enough, depending on the audio quality of your computer input. However, if you want to start making a song, laying down multiple tracks, you may need better monitoring / latency compensation, etc. Basically, there are reasons why people often buy a dedicated audio interface even if the signal level is good enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I am planning to build my own circuit to sample guitar's input at higher bit depth and sample rates. So If it is amplified enough to get sampled it is enough for me.